# jQuery easing with "jquery.paginatetable.js" and tables

Tags: jquery, jquery-easing

I am trying to figure how to enable easing with "jquery.pagenate.js".  I've done a bunch searching but it seems no one has done this?  I was under the impression you can add easing to anything.

Currently, the new pages just 'appear' without any easing or speed control... I thought I could do a easing.paginatetable but that's not working either.

Any insight from a Jquery ninja would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a easing option for this plugin.  It has been suggested to the developer and he has put out the word for help on github to possibly undertake this task.